# Align two elements on the same line in the same <td> tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to align two ASPx elements in a same table cell. Here are my aspx code :

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Select customer:</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtCust" runat="server" Width="220px" Height="46px"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
                <dx:ASPxButton  ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" Image-Url="~/IMG/search32.png" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Here's what I'm trying to do in my CSS :

```
#btnSearch 
{
   display:inline; 
}

#txtCust 
{
 display:inline;
}
```

As I'm pretty new in CSS, I'm aware that it's not enough but I still have no clue about what to do to get my two objects aligned in the same cell. Any idea guys?

EDIT : Here's what I'm getting... I'd like my search button to be align on the same line that my textbox.

[image]

Comment: aligned vertically?  Can you post current output as in a picture (probably with the output html)?

Comment: What is the HTML code generated for those server controls? The HTML elements for a textbox (`input type="text"`) and a button (`input type="button"`) are already inline elements and would be on the same line.

Comment: Please see the screenshot I've posted in my updated post. The html will follow.

Comment: You should post an example of actual HTML code generated, not ASP code, and include sufficient HTML and CSS code for actually reproducing the issue.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela that won't help OP write ASP code.

Comment: @paqogomez, in rendering the ASP code does not matter; the browser gets only the generated HTML and associated CSS, so the problem must first be solved at that level. Then you may need to find out how to modify the ASP code accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The collective width of the two elements is more than the width of the `<td>` element. This is causing it to wrap the second element to a new line.